White noise when Exoplayer streams music to discord bot
I'm trying to stream audio bytes to a discord bot, but instead of music there's a lot of noise. Moreover, the bot connects successfully, the codec works. The first thing that comes to mind is that I either take the data in the wrong place, or I transfer it to the bot incorrectly. Moreover, the bot itself works correctly, it connects to the voice channel correctly, and even recognizes sounds, but not the correct ones. I use Exoplayer to play a local mp3 file on the device itself and in Discord. It plays on the phone itself without problems
Discord Bot requrements
To work with discord bots I use Kord. Its requirements for transmitted data are described in the documentation:

A frame of 20ms Opus-encoded 48k stereo audio data.

Codec settings
Based on this, I set the following codec settings, as per the requirement:
@OptIn(UnstableApi::class)
class BotAudioProcessor(
    private val audioDataListener: AudioDataListener
): BaseAudioProcessor(){
    val codec = Opus()
    val SAMPLE_RATE = Constants.SampleRate._48000()
    val CHANNELS = Constants.Channels.stereo()
    val APPLICATION = Constants.Application.audio()
    val FRAME_SIZE = Constants.FrameSize._960()
    val COMPLEXITY = Constants.Complexity.instance(10)
    val BITRATE = Constants.Bitrate.max()

    init {
        codec.encoderInit(SAMPLE_RATE, CHANNELS, APPLICATION)
        codec.encoderSetComplexity(COMPLEXITY)
        codec.encoderSetBitrate(BITRATE)
    }

    override fun onConfigure(inputFormat: AudioProcessor.AudioFormat): AudioProcessor.AudioFormat {
        val outputFormat = AudioProcessor.AudioFormat(
            SAMPLE_RATE.v,
            CHANNELS.v,
            C.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
        )
        return outputFormat
    }
    //... queueInput()
}

Here I set all the parameters as requested in the documentation. All these values ​​were set via the codec, the only thing is that I spent an hour calculating the frame size
frame size = SAMPLE_RATE * 0.02 (20ms) = 960
Getting audio streaming
If I understand correctly, uncompressed PCM streams can be obtained using AudioProcessor, for this, I inherit from BaseAudioProcessor and override the queueInput method, in which I encode the buffer in Opus format, and then pass it to the listener, which will send the stream to the discord bot.
override fun queueInput(inputBuffer: ByteBuffer) {
    if (inputBuffer.remaining() < FRAME_SIZE.v / 2) {
        Log.e("BotAudioProcessor", "Input buffer too small")
        return
    }
    val frame = ShortArray( FRAME_SIZE.v / 2)
    inputBuffer.asShortBuffer().get(frame)
    val encoded = codec.encode(frame, FRAME_SIZE)

    audioDataListener.onAudioData(encoded!!.toByteArray())
}

Stream data to the bot
Next, the received audio stream is saved in a variable, which is then broadcast by the bot.
@UnstableApi
class MusicBot(...) : AudioDataListener {
    private var audioData: ByteArray? = null
    //...

    @OptIn(KordVoice::class)
    suspend fun start() {
        kord!!.on<ReadyEvent> {
            //...
            voiceChannel.connect {
                audioProvider {
                    println(audioBuffer?.joinToString(" "))
                    println(audioBuffer?.size)
                    audioBuffer?.let { AudioFrame(it) }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onAudioData(data: ByteArray) {
        audioBuffer = data
    }
}

Links and Additionally

kord library: https://github.com/kordlib/kord/tree/main/voice
Opuc codec: https://github.com/theeasiestway/android-opus-codec
use audioprocessor: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/8342


This is how I connect it to the player
@OptIn(UnstableApi::class)
class DiscordRendersFactory
    (
    context: Context,
    private val audioDataListener: AudioDataListener
) : DefaultRenderersFactory(context) {

    override fun buildAudioSink(
        context: Context,
        enableFloatOutput: Boolean,
        enableAudioTrackPlaybackParams: Boolean
    ): AudioSink {

        val defaultAudioSink = DefaultAudioSink.Builder()
            .setAudioProcessors(arrayOf(BotAudioProcessor(audioDataListener)))
            .setEnableFloatOutput(true)
            .setEnableAudioTrackPlaybackParams(enableAudioTrackPlaybackParams)
            .build()
        return defaultAudioSink
    }
}


In the queueInput method you receive an inputBuffer full of audio samples. You encode and send the first FRAME_SIZE bytes of it. The rest of the samples are thrown away.
AFAIK Opus uses 20 ms long frames by default. So you probably don't need to slice the buffers at all.
But if you do, you should make sure that you process all samples in each buffer. You also need to take care of leftovers (slices of length < FRAME_SIZE).
